# String Replace Not Working

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting a value through Query string but facing some problem in printing that value

The query string is

```
http://mastertrade.in/master/wpfiles/corp_announcements.php?tpnt=5544&caption=%22KNRCON%20-%20Press%20Release%22
```

Then I am getting the caption with GET method like this

$cap=$_GET['caption'];

While print this Variable $cap
am getting this

```
\"KNRCON - Press Release\"
```

I dont want

> \

while print what should I do ?
I tried

```
preg_replace('/\/','',$cap);
```

But I am getting

```
 preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: No ending matching delimiter '/'
```

Comment: Have you tried stripslashes() ? If you really want to preg_replace, try preg_replace('!\/!', '', $cap);

Comment: preg_replace('!\/!', '', $cap);
is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$string = '\"KNRCON - Press Release\"';    
echo str_replace(array('\/','\\'),'',$string);  //Output: "KNRCON - Press Release"
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a function to remove the escape slashes [stripslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

```
$cap = stripslashes($cap);
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice answers. But noone suggested just to turn Magic Quotes off. Or use `get_magic_quotes_gpc`/.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php

```
$caption = $_GET['caption'];
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $caption = stripslashes($caption);
}
```